# AWS cognitos - Federated Identities

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS and learning about Cognito - Federated Identities.

I have requirement in my project where I need to authenticate user against Active directory (SAML authentication Provider) and then use Cognito to provide access token. This requirement is as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html under External Provider Authflow >> Enhanced (Simplified) Authflow.

So basically following steps: -

- Login in into AD and get Id/auth token
- Pass this token to Cognito which internally validates against AD (SAML provider) and issues an access token (JWT token)
- User/Client uses the above token to access AWS resources.

Here is my question:-

Can this be done as per following steps?

- User/Client passes username and password to Cognito.
- Cognito authenticates the credentials with AD and generates an access token
- User/Client uses the above token to access AWS resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say AD. Is it internal or in Cloud?

Comment: It is internal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in the flow you mentioned if you connect Cognito Federated Identities with SAML.

1. User wants Login and he/she redirected to O365 domain login page by your application.
2. Once credentials are given there, it will redirect back to the defined application URL with a token.
3. Pass that token to Cognito Federated identities and get a AWS access tokens which can be used to access AWS resources.

Note: If you use Cognito Userpools connected with Cognito Federated Identity Pool, you can eliminate handling the first step manually if you connect the Userpool to AD using SAML. It will also provide the Login UI with Hosted UI feature. However this approach adds a cost to monthly active federated users above the free tier of 50 and suits better if you plan to use multiple authentication mechanisms like Google, Facebook and self-signup.

Comment: Lets say I use Cognito userpools connected with Cognito Federated Identity pool and eliminate the first step. I do not want to have Login with hosted UI feature or any other login UI. 

Is the following true :-

- On calling some Cognito API with username and password it will   automatically call the configured User pool Federated Identity provider to authenticate the user and then generate the JWT token.  If yes can you please refer/guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Ashan for you answer. I posted my subsequent question in comment above as separate post as well.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067438/aws-cognitos-user-pools-with-federated-identity-providers
Thanks again.