# AWS Cognito - User Pools with Federated Identity providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am new to AWS and learning about Cognito Pools.

I am planning to use Cognito userpools connected with Cognito Federated Identity pool. I do not want to use Login with hosted UI feature or any other login UI to log in.

Is the following true/possible :-

- From back end on calling some Cognito API with username and password it can automatically call the configured User pool Federated Identity provider to authenticate the user and then generate the JWT token.  If yes can you please refer/guide me please.
- User present in Identity provider does not exist in AWS user pool. Is it possible to authenticate the user with configured Identity provider without the user being present in AWS user pool? If yes then will the user be created in AWS User pool after authentication?

I will really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> From back end on calling some Cognito API with username and password
> it can automatically call the configured User pool Federated Identity
> provider to authenticate the user and then generate the JWT token. If
> yes can you please refer/guide me please.

This is possible. You can use a combination of the following two references.

[Receiving the JWT token from Cognito UserPools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

```
    var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Password : 'password',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_xxxxx',
        ClientId : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
            console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },

    });
```

Pass the JWT Token to the [Cognito Federated Identity Pool via SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getOpenIdToken-property) and exchange for AWS Temporary access credentials to perform any action against AWS provisioning.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx',
   Logins: {
      'cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_xxxxxx': result.idToken.jwtToken
   }
});
```

> User present in Identity provider does not exist in AWS user pool. Is
> it possible to authenticate the user with configured Identity provider
> without the user being present in AWS user pool? If yes then will the
> user be created in AWS User pool after authentication?

This is only possible if your external Identity Provider supports SAML Federation.

Comment: Ashan Thanks for quick reply. The implementation for Receiving the JWT token from Cognito UserPools is in javascript. My requirement is to implement this in backend using GOlang and expose it through webservice. I looked at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go and dont see corresponding classes. Can you please help/guide?